# How to have two digits after comma in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, calculated-field

I am trying to make calculation in my model, but i'm not able to get two digits after the comma.

I tried different ways but when my result should be for example 7.50 or 7.25 I get 7 or 8.

if you can tell me where the issue is, that would be very kind of you. Thanks.

My schema.rb

```html
  create_table "timesheets", force: true do |t|
    t.time     "working_start"
    t.time     "working_end"
    t.decimal  "billable_hours"
    t.integer  "weeknum"
    t.date     "date"
    t.decimal  "breaks"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

My model

```html
class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
## current week number

default_value_for :weeknum do
    Time.now.strftime('%V')
end

## relation

belongs_to :user

## Worked hours

before_create :calculate_worked_hours

private
    def calculate_worked_hours
      #breacalculk = (breaks.to_i * 60)
      #totalhours = (working_end.to_i - working_start.to_i) - (breaks.to_i * 60)
      
      self.billable_hours = ((working_end.to_i - working_start.to_i) - (breaks.to_i * 60)) / 3600
    end

end
```

Comment: Hi Deep, So what should I put ?

Comment: Try this: `((working_end.to_i - working_start.to_i) - (breaks.to_i * 60)).to_f / 3600.0`

Comment: I also tried .to_s, but I just tried       workcalcul = ((working_end. - working_start) - (breaks * 60)) / 3600, and it works now. But thanks for yor help

Comment: `.to_s` converts it into string. For float value you have `.to_f`. Just to be sure that always it gives you decimal value use `.to_f` or use `3600.0` as @Prakash Murthy said.

Comment: I tried your method and it also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `/ 3600` to `/ 3600.0`

When both numerator and denominator are integers, the result will be an integer; so `5/2` will give `2`. If one of them is a float, then the result will be a float. Eg: `5.0/2` = `2.5`

Comment: hi Prakash,  
I also tried .to_s, but I just tried workcalcul = ((working_end. - working_start) - (breaks * 60)) / 3600, and it works now. But thanks for yor help –